# UL display: block

Tags: html, css

I am not sure if this is the right way to do this but I am trying to align a number of ULs beside each other and should drop the third UL when the screen size is smaller. I just need help with the CSS because for some reason, they keep stacking on top of one another even though I already changed the width to 50%. I already created the '@media'.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Content 1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Content 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Content 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { 
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
   ul { 
    width: 50%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle please

Comment: try `display:inline-table`

Comment: Try `@media screen and (max-width: 767px)`

Comment: @MevinBabu still nothing.

Comment: @karthikr doesn't change anything

Comment: Are you sure you reset the padding and margins on those `ul` elements? 50% + anything = No room for 2 side by side

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `display: block`, and `width: 100%`. And make display: inline-block

```
ul { 
 display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Since making width: 100% will cover up the whole width, you are getting the uls one down another

Comment: `float:left` cancels inline-block behavior, changes it to `block`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `@media`.

You need to use `display:inline` on your lists.

Have a look here:  **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cfxg8/)**

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>Content 1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Content 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Content 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { 
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
}
```

You can see it over here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GwBak

Try changing the window size .

Answer (score 0):

CSS code

```
{
        display: block;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #036;
        width: 9em;
        padding: 3px 12px 3px 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        }

        #navcontainer a:hover
        {
        background-color: #369;
        color: #FFF;
        }
```

In html code

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Milk</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Goat</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Cow</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Eggs</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Free-range</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Cheese</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Smelly</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Extra smelly</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```