# What I am styling here (ul, li or a)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have one CSS file which I found it in one website, but I have a confusion about it. The code is:

```
ul li a {
background-color: FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid 86B3E6;
color: 2F62AC;
display: block;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: -1px;
padding: 12px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
direction:rtl;
}
```

So, what I am styling here? as I know, it should be (( a )) tag, so if I add

```
display:inline-block;
```

to (( ul )) tag styling which I found here (( [UL display: block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172898/ul-display-block) )) it should work, but unfortunately I failed to make it.

Maybe I will have one more question later, but for timing i want to understand the code and correct my information.

Best regards and thanks in advance,

Gharib

edit:
I want to use both inline-block and block, and here is my full code:

```
ul.ablock {
display: block;
}
ul.aninline {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
width: 50%;
}
a {
background-color: FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid 86B3E6;
color: 2F62AC;
display: block;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: -1px;
padding: 12px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
direction:rtl;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
a:active, a:hover {
background-color:2F62AC;
color:FFFFFF;
}
```

and the html is something like:

```
<ul class="ablock">
<li><a href="#" onclick="mSearch($('#SearchText').val());"><div align="center">Find</div></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="aninline">
<li><a href="#"><div align="center">Back</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><div align="center">Next</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are styling the a's that are children of li's that are in their turn children of uls

Comment: I edit my post, so please help me in that.

Answer (score 2):

The above selector will target all `a` elements which are nested under `li` which is further nested under `ul`, that's a general element selector, which will target all the `a` element which falls in that pattern. It is better to be specific and use a `class` instead, like

```
ul.class_name li a {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

The above selector will only target `a` elements which are nested under `li` which are further nested under an `ul` element having a `class` called `.class_name`

---

As you commented, it seems like you want to target a `ul` element, now instead of using something like

```
ul {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Will apply the styles to all the `ul` elements, instead, be specific, either assign a `class` to your `ul` element and use a selector like

```
ul.class_name {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Or you can also use a nested selector like

```
div.wrapper_div ul {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Here, in the above selector we are selecting all the `ul` which are nested under `.wrapper_div`.

---

Just a side note, you seem to be confused so don't wanna confuse you more, so don't read this, you can simply ignore, but if you want to learn, just make sure that, if you are targeting `ul`, make sure you use `>` selector which will select direct child, as users tend to nest a `ul` element under `li`, say for example dropdown menu, this is common, so it is better to use a selector like

```
div.class_name > ul { /* Selects first level ul elements */
   /* Styles goes here */
}

ul > li > ul { /* Selects nested level ul elements */
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Comment: @Mr. Alien ((ul > li > ul)) this is new for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting the `<a>` element here. The reason for the `ul` and `li` is that, you're targeting a specific nesting of `a`. Namely, you are targeting a `<a>` that is a descendant of `<li>` that is in turn, a descendant of a `<ul>`.

If you want to add `dispay: inline-block` to all `<ul>` elements then above the rule for `ul li a` you want to add:

```
ul { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Not just any a the ones that are children of `li`s

Comment: @PatsyIssa I know. Originally I thought he meant which out of the three is trying to style, but just edited my answer to cover ambiguities

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Then why I am unable to style ul inline?

Comment: @Gharib I have added to the answer

Comment: You're not really targeting a specific _kind_ of `<a>`, but an `<a>` in a specific placement within its parents. Also, the space in the selector is the "descendant selector", not the direct child selector which would be a `>`

Comment: @bojangles Don't you mean a specific placement within its ancestors ;) We can all be pedantic.